Rules for calculating the energy-momentum tensor
I am trying to understand a crucial step in the derivation of the energy-momentum tensor for a given lagrangian density:
We are given for a real scalar field:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac 1 2(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi) -\frac 1 2m^2\phi^2-\frac {1}{4!}\lambda\phi^4$$
The energy-momentum operator is:
$$T_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi-g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.$$
So I don't understand how the $\frac 1 2$ factror in the kinetic term vanishes?
I was thinking of incorporating the metric tensor in the equation to have something like:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac 1 2(\partial_\mu\phi)(g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\phi) -\frac 1 2m^2\phi^2-\frac {1}{4!}\lambda\phi^4$$ so that one would differentiate twice, and somehow eliminate the two. But for calculating the energy-momentum tensor, the expression is something like:
$$T^{\mu\nu}= \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\partial^\nu\phi-g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$
So I am deriving w.r.t $\partial_\mu$. I cannot differentiate the second bracket where $\partial_\nu$ is present.
Can someone explain this to me?

$x\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x^2$

In the expression $$\mathcal L_0=\frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} (\partial_\alpha \phi) (\partial_\beta \phi),  $$ the indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are summation indices. On the other hand, in the formula $$\frac{\partial \mathcal L_0}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)},$$ the index $\mu$ is a free index. Performing yor calculation correctly, one obtains $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial \mathcal L_0}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi)} \left[\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha \beta}(\partial_\alpha \phi) (\partial_\beta \phi)   \right]\\[5pt] &=\frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} \left[\delta^\mu_\alpha (\partial_\beta \phi)+(\partial_\alpha \phi)\delta^\mu_\beta\right] \\[5pt] &=\frac{1}{2}\left[g^{\mu \beta} \partial_\beta \phi + g^{\alpha \mu}\partial_\alpha \phi\right]\\[5pt]&=\partial^\mu \phi. \end{align}$$
